# jQuery animate to variable height

Tags: jquery, variables

I want a button above the fold, that says "scroll down!" When clicked. I want it to animate the full browser height down. Since people have different screen resolutions. I want to use a variable. However this is quite impossible.

The code below works, but only with a set height of 800px.

Instead I need it to work with the `var hheight`.

I've been searching stackoverflow all night with only few leads to follow, and no real solutions.

This is working:

```
function jqUpdateSize(){
    // Get the dimensions of the viewport
    var width = jQuery(window).width();
    var hheight = jQuery(window).height();

    jQuery('#jqWidth').html(width);
    jQuery('#jqHeight').html(hheight);
};
jQuery(document).ready(jqUpdateSize);    // When the page first loads
jQuery(window).resize(jqUpdateSize);     // When the browser changes size

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".my-btn").click(function(event){
    jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop:'+=' + 800 + 'px'}, '800');
    });
});
```

Following is not working:

```
jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop:'+=' + hheight+ 'px'}, '800');
```

Hope someone, knows how to handle this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need an anonymous function in `ready()` and `resize()`

So,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){jqUpdateSize();});
jQuery(window).resize(function(){jqUpdateSize();});
```

Otherwise, your `jqUpdateSize` function never gets called and your variable `hheight` has nothing in it

Best practice would be to put all of it in the `document.ready()`

Like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jqUpdateSize();
    jQuery(window).resize(function(){jqUpdateSize();});
    jQuery(".my-btn").click(function(event){
        jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop:'+=' + hheight + 'px'}, '800');
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi, And thanks you are both correct, had help from my programmer this morning, we came up with this:

Comment: Ahh.. cant paste code in comments, but He saw that my var wasn't global. And therefor empty. Together with parseInt(hheight) we made it work :) U can se the function in effect on www.onlinebrand.dk

Answer (score 0):

```
var hheight = jQuery(window).height();
jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop:'+=' + hheight+ 'px'}, '800');
```

this work's fine  --- [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DXj87/4/)

Try moving this  `jQuery(window).resize(jqUpdateSize);` in `ready`

it should look like this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(window).resize(jqUpdateSize);
    jQuery(".my-btn").click(function(event){
    jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop:'+=' + 800 + 'px'}, '800');
    });
});
```